# How can I set values of DynamicForm data in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, dynamicform

I'm trying to fetch previous values of a form from cache, clear one value and render the form with all the previous values except the one cleared.

```
DynamicForm dform = (DynamicForm) Cache.get("dform");
Cache.set("dform",null,0);
if (dform == null) {
  dform = new DynamicForm();
} else {
  dform.data().put("name","");
}
return ok(myform.render(dform));
```

Everything else works like expected except `dform.data().put("name","")` does not change the value of name field. Why? How can I set that field's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From play 2.1, you can't change data. If you want to change it, you need to do the following:

```
Map<String,String> data = dform.data();
data.put("name", "");
dform = new DynamicForm().fill(data);
```

Good luck.